# Can someone become immune to the Death Note by using plastic surgery?

Tags: death-note

If someone were to change his face through plastic surgery, would he become immune to the Death Note?

Comment: While the question is only slightly similar on a superficial level, the idea is identical. [This](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23308/2604) is also similar, although the scope of change is different. (This is an edited version of an old comment, since there was a confusing-looking typo there.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [rule I](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note):

> This note will not take effect unless the writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name. Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.

Plastic surgery might stop photos of the old appearance from working, but unlike with the name, it has not been stated that the original appearance is required to kill a target.

Conclusion, No. Plastic surgery can not make one immune for the the death note.